# Users getting 'flooded' with not read notifications (NRNs) for old emails and meeting requests

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, outlook, windows-sbs

I'm being placed under quite a lot of pressure from senior management over a relatively trivial issue. Basically the vast majority of users are complaining that they receive not read notifications (NRNs) for old emails and meeting requests in large numbers multiple times a day. I know something strange is happening because some are delivered at silly times in the morning (i.e 3AM or 4AM).

The problem I have is that these some of these NRNs are from meeting requests and messages that are 120 days old, so some users have deleted the original message so I don’t actually know if the NRN is from an email or meeting request.

This is typical of what users receive as a NRN:

```
From: Sender 
Sent: 23 March 2012 04:16
To: Recepient
Subject: Not read: Accepted: Status update

Your message 

   To: Sender 
   Subject: Accepted: Status update
   Sent: Wednesday, November 23, 2011 8:59:00 AM (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London

 was deleted without being read on Friday, March 23, 2012 4:15:32 AM (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London.
```

...

```
From: Sender 
Sent: 18 March 2012 01:13
To: Recepient
Subject: Not read: Gold delivery - Sourcing module


Your message 

   To: Sender
   Subject: Gold delivery - Sourcing module 
   Sent: Friday, November 18, 2011 9:37:58 AM (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London

 was deleted without being read on Sunday, March 18, 2012 1:12:37 AM (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London.
```

I have done a search and found the following:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544246

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2471964

But we already installed 'Update Rollup 6 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 1' back in December, so I am not sure what we can do to fix this?

BTW we are running Windows Small Business Server 2011

Comment: Did you see this note: `Note The NRNs are not completely flushed until 120 days have passed after the hotfix is installed.`  Has it been 120 days since the update rollup was applied?

Comment: I did but I was hoping I would not have to wait 120 days! I have just checked when the update was installed (which was 103 days ago). Can anyone confirm that this will fix the problem once the NRN queue has been fulshed? and that there is no way of speeding this process up?

Comment: It seems that your problem is exactly matching the one fixed by this update, so it seems reasonable that after 120 days your problem will go away.  But I can't **confirm** for sure that it will.

Comment: @Exile Did it go away after 120 days?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Yes it has now 121+ days has elapsed! If I have anymore problematic NRNs from 120 days ago I will post here to let you guys know. I also made a post on technet about this which you can read here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/4f499a46-252d-471f-aeb1-5484de0183dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Update Rollup 6 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 1' seemed to fix my problem after waiting over 121 days.